# How can I put element in the middle of vertical align?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/6/) with JSfiddle so please check.

This show a comment that slides from right side to very left.
It's shown just a little bit above than middle of vertical align.

How can I show it right in middle?
Please fix and update my JSfiddle

**Javascript**

```
function transition() {

        $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600).fadeOut(100);
        $('.newsticker').append("<p style='margin-left:400px;opacity:0'>Hello! This is a test</p>");
        $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);

}

setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

**CSS**

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.newsticker p{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="newsticker"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for keeping `.newsticker p{position:absolute;}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: @NathanLee No. You can take it off if you want

Comment: It does affect. It goes to the bottom and then animated back to top. - @HUSTEN. If you think it is not affecting, I suggest you to remove it and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reset browsers default stylesheet like `margin` or `padding` by:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then add `line-height: 100px;` CSS declaration to the `.newsticker` element:

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:100px; /* --------  */
    line-height: 100px; /*  |  */
             /*   ^----------  */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/azHVv/9/)**

### Update

By using CSS, it is almost impossible to achieve this goal. I create a jQuery version, It calculates `height` of the dynamic paragraph and set `top` property to get it to the middle of its parent. In this case a little change is needed in CSS:

**CSS:**

```css
div.newsticker {
    position: relative; /* Add relative position to the parent */
    overflow: hidden;   /* Hide the overflow */
}

.newsticker p {
    width: 100%;       /* Set the width of paragraph to '100%' or 'inherit' */
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```javascript
var newsticker = $('.newsticker'),
    maxHeight = newsticker.height();

function transition() {
    newsticker.find('p').animate({
        marginLeft : "400px",
        opacity : ".0"
    }, 600).fadeOut(100);

    newsticker.append(
        $('<p>').css({
            'margin-left' : '400px',
            'opacity'     : '0'
        // Put your text in .text() method:
        }).text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam suscipit nihil voluptatibus maxime sit quam delectus eaque officiis cumque accusamus velit nesciunt deserunt veniam molestias alias? Eaque iste quia non.')
    ).find('p').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('top') == 'auto')
        $(this).css('top',
            (maxHeight - $(this).height()) / 2
        );
    });

    newsticker.find('p').animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
}
setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/azHVv/24/)**.

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/14/ if the text is kinda long, it messes up.

Comment: what if I don't wanna use `* {padding: 0;margin: 0;}` ? how can you change? because I want margin. If I take it off, now it won't be in the middle anymore:(

Comment: @HUSTEN Set `padding: 0; margin: 0` only to `.newsticker p` selector ;) I just applied that rule to every element as a demo

Answer (score 1):

### **UPDATE**

new Fiddle: [New JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eySHH/12/)

HTML:

```
<div class="newsticker"> 
    <div class="middle"><p><p></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    function transition() {

        $('.middle').animate({"right":"-100%","opacity":".0"}, 600, function() {
            $('.middle').first().remove();
        });

        var width = $('.newsticker').width();
        $('.newsticker').append("<div class='middle'><p style='width: " + width + "px;'>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p></div>");
        var height = $('.middle p').last().height() / 2;
        $('.middle p').css('top','-' + height + 'px');
        $('.middle').animate({"right":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
    }

setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

CSS:

```
   div.newsticker{
        border:1px solid #666666;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
         overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    }

.newsticker p{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    line-height: 1em; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.middle {position: absolute; top: 50%; padding:0; margin:0; right: -100%; opacity: 0;}
```

---

### **ORIGINAL ANSWER**

here is the working fiddle

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eySHH/)

you needed 100px line-height on your p tag and you needed to reset padding and margin on your `div` and `p`

```
 div.newsticker{
        border:1px solid #666666;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
 }

    .newsticker p{
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        float:left;
        position:absolute;
        line-height: 100px; 
        padding: 0px; 
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

also made some improvements to your animation:

```
function transition() {

    $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"400px","opacity":".0"}, 600, function() {
         $('.newsticker p').remove();
        $('.newsticker').append("<p style='margin-left:400px;opacity:0'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam </p>");
        $('.newsticker p').animate({"marginLeft":"0px","opacity":"1"}, 600);
    });                 
} 
setInterval(transition, 2000);
```

you have to start with this:

```
<div class="newsticker"> 
        <p><p>
 </div>
```

Comment: But look at my update http://jsfiddle.net/eySHH/1  If the text is kinda long, it messes up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eySHH/5/ now? if not pls give me more info what is still wrong in your opinion

Comment: Please size down the width of the window, and you'll notice it won't show whole text. In fact, it has to be 2 lines.

Comment: Updated my Answer to your needs!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle, you can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/20/)

This is the css applied on parent and child respectively

```
//parent
position:relative;

//child
position:absolute/relative;
top:50%;
height:x;
margin-top:-x/2; // half the height
```

There are two ways to vertically center align a block.

1. Take top position to 50%, and negative margin to half the height of block. This will force it to align vertically center. This is useful only when you know the size of the block.
2. Use the display technique. Apply 'display:table-cell' to the parent container and for the child container use 'vertical-align:middle' property. This will align your block vertically whatever the size may change to.

Comment: Please see this. this won't be in right in middle anymore if text gets long. http://jsfiddle.net/azHVv/21/

Comment: If your text is dynamic please follow the second approach. Or use JavaScript to dynamically update the margin-top property of the block to half of it's display height.